# Unwinding Segue Error at Second View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, unwind-segue

I was trying to figure out how to implement a custom segue so that the user would be able to swipe up the screen to access the storyboard below with the help of this tutorial (http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/). It worked without problems until the part where the rewinding segue part needed to be implemented and I kept getting errors with this block of code:

```
override func segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController: UIViewController, fromViewController: UIViewController, identifier: String?) -> UIStoryboardSegue {
if let id = identifier{
    if id == "idFirstSegueUnwind" {
        let unwindSegue = FirstCustomSegueUnwind(identifier: id, source: fromViewController, destination: toViewController, performHandler: { () -> Void in

        })
        return unwindSegue
    }        
}

return super.segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController, fromViewController: fromViewController, identifier: identifier)
```

}

Especially with this line:

```
return super.segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController, fromViewController: fromViewController, identifier: identifier)
```

It gives an error like this: **Value of optional type 'UIStoryboardSegue?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?**

I tried replacing it with this line of code, thinking maybe there was a problem with the parameters:

```
return super.segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController: UIViewController, fromViewController: UIViewController, identifier: String?)
```

but this time I get a **missing argument for parameter "fromViewController" in call** error.

Anyone that has any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: For your error message maybe it works: (Just add ! end of the line)
return super.segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController, fromViewController: fromViewController, identifier: identifier)!

Comment: When I do that it builds, but gives an error when i try to swipe up to trigger the segue unwind. It directs me to the AppDelegate page and highlights the **class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {** part then gives the error **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**

Answer (score 0):

You have to unwrap the optional type UIStoryboardSegue with "!" :

```
return super.segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController, fromViewController: fromViewController, identifier: identifier)!
```